# Grails one-to-many using natural ID and referenced column name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following entities:

```
class ProductVariant {
    int id
    long sku

    static hasMany = [prices: ProductPrice]
}

class ProductPrice {
    int id
    int priceBandId
    long sku
    BigDecimal price
}
```

I am trying to achieve a one-to-many relationship between `ProductVariant` and `ProductPrice` where the join is on the `sku` as opposed to the `id` column.

I have seen an example of how this works in Hibernate using a `@NaturalId` annotation on the `sku` column and a `referencedColumnName` property in the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Is is possible to achieve the same thing using Grails/GORM?

The key thing here is that each store has its own set of variants with their own IDs, but the prices are set at a SKU level and would apply across all stores stocking the same SKU.

Comment: Is it the case that you want both `ProductPrice ` and `ProductVariant` to have both `int id` and `long sku` and you want `sku` to be a foreign key from one that points to the other, and in addition to that you want each of the `id` to be the primary key for their respective classes?  If you just want to use `sku` as the primary key, that is trivial, but it looks like you may want both, which may not be.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it's exactly what you described (primary key id AND a separate sku). You're right, it doesn't appear to be easily possible so now I'm shuffling things around a bit to see whether I can make it a bit more standard.

Comment: I believe it is possible in most RDBMS to create a foreign key that references a column that is *not* a primary key.

Comment: Yeah at the database level it's fine, it's just proven difficult to get GORM to allow me to do it so. I've given up on this and posted an answer with how I've gone about it instead.

Comment: "Yeah at the database level it's fine, it's just proven difficult to get GORM to allow me to do it so." - GORM doesn't have to do it.  The usual thing for a situation like this is to create the foreign key in the database, independent of the ORM tool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that, whilst this is fine at the database level, it's not really something you do. Grails won't let you have a `hasMany` association on just one part of the primary key.

Instead I am just retrieving all prices by adding a getter to my `ProductVariant` domain object as follows:

```
List<ProductPrice> getPrices() {
    return ProductPrice.findAll { it.sku == this.sku }
}
```

and then I can just use `productVariant.prices` when needed.

Comment: "Grails won't let you have a hasMany association on just one part of the primary key." - Your response to a question in a comment above indicates that you want the primary key to be `id`', which makes sense and is supported.

Comment: Does `ProductPrice.findAll { sku == sku }` give you the same results as `ProductPrice.findAll { it.sku == this.sku }`?